# Is there a way to slice a string in which you know the start index while only knowing which value you want to end at in Python?

Tags: python, string, slice

I'm writing some code that returns the number of views the top Youtube video has based on the search query. The substring starts at index 101, the problem is that not all video views are listed with the same length. For example, "6.8M views" has a length of 10 while "5B views" has just 8. Is there a way to implement a string slice as shown below?

```
numOfViews = list[101:ends with "views"]
```

To be clear, I just need the first occurrence of "views" after index 101.

Comment: ```x = re.search('views$', str)```? You will know the index of views

Comment: @Sujay. The portion of interest ends with "views", not the whole string

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It doesn't matter what the string comes from, only what it looks like. Replace 101 with something more manageable. See [ask] for ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) and [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) accept a `start` parameter. You can therefore find the first instance of "views" following index 101 using

```
index_of_views = string.find(" views", 101)
```

The substring containing the number of views is then

```
num_of_views = string[101:index_of_views]
```